# PHP retrieve last name from full name, where last name is unknown

Tags: php

Basic question for PHP experts out there.

I'm writing a page where the variable I receive will be somebody's full name, the two words will be separated by a space. Thus, I know that the second word, after the space will be the last name. I would like to retrieve this last name and hold it in a variable.

For example: `$EditorName = "John Doe"`

I would like to have the result `$LastName = "Doe"`

Can I use some variation of the `split` in the PHP manual.

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$names=explode(' ',$EditorName);
$LastName=$names[1]
```

[PHP Manual: explode](http://php.net/explode)

If you need really last(not second) name you should use

```
$LastName=array_pop($names) instead
```

Comment: What if editor has more names? `Joe Pedro Doe` would return `Pedro`.

Comment: @Ondrej: from the question: the two words will be separated by a space

Comment: @pedro -- i agree that would be a problem -- cause I wouldn't if there were three wouldn't would need to call up the third member of the array, i.e. $names[2] (but right now - I'm expecting only two names)

Answer (score 1):

```
$EditorName = "John Doe";
$tmp = explode(" ", $EditorName);
$LastName = $tmp[1];
echo $LastName;
```

http://codepad.org/JEZXZHJR

But, what about people with middle names? More than one space in their surname?
I hope former german minister [Karl Theodor Maria Nikolaus Johann Jacob Philipp Franz Joseph Sylvester Freiherr von und zu Guttenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl-Theodor_zu_Guttenberg) doesn't use your script!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex(Regular Expressions) to extract Last name from Full name.

```
\s([a-zA-Z]*)
```

Extract results from matched group 1.